# Error during undo checkout of item

Tags: 5.3

I am using Tridion R 5.3. I am getting exception while doing undo checkout of a component. It is always showing message "The title is not unique". Exception message is as below:

```
Unable to Undo Check-out Component (tcm:7-122991). The title is not unique.  Error Code: 0x8004026D (-2147220883)  Call stack: VersioningCommon.UndoCheckoutItem ComponentBL.UndoCheckOut Component.UndoCheckOut
```

Can anyone suggest me the root cause. I have check event viewer, but there is no more information. I can do checkin, but I can't do any change in that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is a bug in Tridion R 5.3. To understand the behavior I have created a component in parent publication with name **xyz**, then localized and renamed to **abc** in child publication. In child publication Then I created a component with name **xyz**. Now I tried to undo-checkout or change content of xyz in parent publication, it is showing the same issue "Title is not unique".

So I think it is the issue with Tridion R 5.3 and the hotfix to fix this bug is not deployed on the CMS server.

Answer (score 4):

It looks that other component is using same name in same folder in blueprint hierarchy, and original component has been renamed with different name. 
In your case maintenance people has updated the name that's why it is showing you original name in master publication.

Suggestion is rename the another component which you have found in blueprint folder and update the master component.

I hope it will be clear to you.

Comment: JFYI: This needs not to be done through backend as it is possible to be done through the CME - This is possible if you create a Component in master pub, localize it in child and rename it and then create a component with same name in the child

Answer (score 3):

What it seems to indicate is that the title of the component on the previous version (the one you're trying to undo to) is not unique in that folder (or any blueprint child of that folder).

I would try to figure out what is that title, then check if there is another component with that same name in the same folder. Once that's resolved you should be able to undo checkout.

Comment: Thanks Nuno. I have found that someone have renamed a component with same title in child publication. So marking this as the answer. One query please! Is it possible to do that through CME?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - "what" is it that you want to do through CME?

Comment: Mukesh, this is absolutely possible through CME itself - but I doubt this creates any issue. 
@Nuno: The all versions of the Component have same name.
This is possible if you create a Component in master pub, localize it in child and rename it and then create a component with same name in the child

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug with Tridion R5.3.

- Create a Component in Master with Name (say Test)
- Localize in Child and Rename it  to some other name (say Test1)
- Create a component in Child with same name as in Master .i.e Test

Now in master you can't check out and rollback the component.

So basically, you need to resolve this dependency and figure out why someone in the world have done that. Use the Blueprinting properly; either resolve the dependency on this component and correctly use the component localized and updated from Master itself instead of creating it again with the same name in Child publication (A very big task) or just live with it and rename the localized component again to some other name not conflicting with master, remove older version of it in Child publication and I hope you are done.